# Sync Out of range during installation

Tags: installation

I tried to install Ubuntu at 1 of my CPU. The Ubuntu version is ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386 while my CPU using Intel as the processor.

I asked community in IRC #ubuntu and they recommend me to check is my chip set SIS 962L supported or not for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There are different databases for hardware running with Ubuntu, i.e.

https://friendly.ubuntu.com
http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/

Google will show you a lot more, I think.

Do you have a problem with installing Ubuntu?
If you provide more information, maybe someone can help you...